# How to use mysql trim function in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am working on cakephp. I want to use

```
    ORDER BY TRIM( `table`.`name` ) ASC
```

in my sql query. But I really don't know how to do it in cakephp.

My current query is

```
'order' => array(
        'table.name' => 'ASC'
          )
```

please help me out of this.

thanks.

Comment: That won't solve my problem

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
'order' => array(
            'TRIM(`table`.`name`)' => 'ASC'
           )
```

Comment: @adithyan What is the produced sql?